# Google Domain API for iOS with access token

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin, google-domain-api

I am developing an application with Google Domain API which would manage activities. I have some questions:

1) This application is for iOS , however I do not see any reference to Google frameworks/PODs for GoogleClientBuilder. Is iOS not supported?

2) I was able to go through Google Sign in through "GIDSignInButton" and delegate, and get the access token and refresh token.

However the APIs for writing posts in Google Domain

https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/userId/activities

does not have "access token" parameter in the header, however it requires Scope Authorization. In 'GIDSignInButton', there is no option of specifying scope.

I have already referred to https://developers.google.com/+/domains/ , the JAVA code mentioned is not at all useful.

I would be grateful, if I can get some direction on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two-way to authenticate the user through Google and implement any other Google API services.

1.Using Google API-Objective C client, which is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client).

Using this method, You can implement the sign in and its has several sample code like Google +, Blogger API integration.

2 Using [Google Sign-In for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating), which is framework based implementation.

In this method, you need to authenticate the user, once the user is authenticated, you can add access token into your each request as a request header.

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}" "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities/user"
```

Please make sure that you have right permission, during the sign In the process in order to get any data during the API.